# How do I create following in json and fetch as array in javascript and search for particular value?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

Basically following is the attached image of a table.

[image]

I do not want to use PHP/Java and any SQL database but want to use only HTML and javascript.

I want to look randomly for any value from the table(url given) like :

> For 1912 year of birth and for 2017 year of termination, I want to have the value 4562.

So I was thinking to put this table in json and fetch/look for the values in javascript/jquery.

Following is the structure I am planning to put in json. Please correct if wrong :

```
    [1910 { 2015 {5316},
            2016 {5230},
            2017 {4444}
          },

     1911 { 2015 {1111},
            2016 {2222},
            2017 {4567}
          }
    ]
```

Comment: You likely mean `{"1910": { "2015":5316,
                "2016":5230,
                "2017":4444
          },
"1911": { "2015":1111,
            "2016": 2222,
            "2017":4567
          }
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an object with key/value pairs where the key (note that a key that is a number needs to be placed in quotes) is the birth date, and the value is an object containing the termination dates:

```
var obj = {
    '1910': { '2015': 5316, '2016':5230, '2017': 4444 },
    '1911': { '2015': 1111, '2016':2222, '2017': 4567 }
}
```

A function to get the data using the birth and termination dates would look something like this:

```
function filter(obj, birth, termination) {
    return obj[birth][termination];
}

filter(obj, 1911, 2017); // 4567
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y40vv6j0/)